How a book recommendation question should be phrased?
I asked a question regarding a book recommendation, which was closed as opinion-based.
I see that this website if full of questions asking book recommendations. Consider this
What are the quantitative finance books that we should all have in our shelves?
When compared, my question is much more specific as I give more context. I give an outdated reference and I ask if there is an updated version. I can't find any recent book dealing with the same topic, if someone knows a title doing so, there is not much of a discretionary judgment. In contrast, in the example above, the recommendation is entirely subjective.
I understand that a book recommendation has always some degree of personal opinions involved, but in this case the book tag should be removed.

I think your question should remain closed because it is quite likely to lead to a forum like discussion with subjective or link-only answers rather than precise and well-thought answers. I am not sure if it can be revised enough, without changing the underlying question, so that it is reopened.
On the other hand, I can understand why the  question you have referred to remains open. Certain questions which do not significantly conform to the current site guidelines may remain open because a) guidelines could have been different before, or b) they could have been answered extensively and similar questions are being asked frequently and they are in accordance with the rest of the guidelines. In addition, whenever possible, it is better to refer to an answer at the same time rather than only closing a question.
Pls note that the information on the "books" tag says "Most questions about books are off topic. Please see past questions and read the FAQ before posting with this tag." but perhaps this could be improved.
